# return expected value when called by variable name

Tags: c#, struct

I want to make a struct that when its value is set, you can call the value by the variable name.

```
struct A
{
   int Value;
}

Main()
{
   // Sets Value to 9
   A Number = 9;
   Console.Write(Number);
   // output should be 9
}
```

I expect the output to be 9

Answer (score 2):

You can optimize your code like this:

```
    struct A
    {
        public int Value;

        public A(int val)
        {
            Value = val;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

and use like you wanted:

```
        // Sets Value to 9
        A Number = new A(9);
        Console.Write(Number);
```

Answer (score 2):

To use exactly what you wrote `A number = 9; Console.Write(Number);` you first need to define an implicit assignment operator, and then you need to override the `ToString()` method to get the right output. Sample code:

```
struct A
{
    public int Value;

    public A(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    // This allows creating an instance of struct A by writing it as an assignment statement
    static public implicit operator A(int value)
    {
        return new A(value);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    A Number = 9;
    Console.Write(Number);
}
```

Live demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WZPsLX

Answer (score 1):

Your struct misses accessors for *Value*

```
    struct A
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
    Main()
    {
        A number = new A();
        number.Value = 9;
        Console.WriteLine(number.Value)
    }
```

Comment: Your code works but your explanation is incorrect: a Struct can contain both fields and properties, and **fields do not have accessors** (or with it, they would be properties).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to  Peter B's answer, you could also define the opposite implicit conversion instead of `ToString()`

```
public static implicit operator int(A a)
{
    return a.Value;
}
```